# How to create a Range Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, diagram

I have no idea how to create souch a range chart in Excel 2010:

[rangechart http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC267977.gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC267977.gif)

My data looks like this:
1, 12, 22
2, 8, 48
3, 22, 42
...

The first column is the x-Value, the second column the lower y-value and the third the higher y-value. That's the yellow area in the graph.

And then the same for the blue one.

Thank you!

Source of the image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456630.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be as follows:
Paste the following into an Excel sheet

```
20% 20% 20% 20% 20%
10% 10% 10% 10% 10.0%
40% 10% -5% 10% 45.0%
20% 20% 20% 20% 20.0%
10% 40% 55% 40% 5%
```

Notice that the sum of each column is 100%

Now add a "stacked area" chart (under the area category of charts) based on this data, and colour the first and third and fifth colours to be white (or transparent)

You can then play with the percentages to get your chart. The top row which is 20% corresponds with a rectangle etc.

Comment: Okay, good idea. But it reorders the lines in my chart :-( Can you upload the Excel file?

Comment: Yeah! It worked. Here's my solution, if anybody needs it: http://www.smallfiles.org/download/791/rangechart.xlsx.html

Answer (score 2):

I would arrange my data in a Table as follows:

```
axis   y_1  h_1 y_2 h_2
1      12    10 30  10
2      8     40 2   4
3      10    12 43  4
4      17    12 18  5
5      30    6  31  5
6      4     7  5   6
7      5     8  6   7
8      2     9  34  8
9      1     4  2   9
```

Then, you can chart the columns y_1, h_1 in the first axis and y_2, h_2 in the second axis (y_i being the y value and h_i being the height of each strip). Make both chart as Stacked Area chart and change the series y_i transparent.

[image]

Finally make the second axis equal to the first one.

Comment: And if I need three areas? Can you upload your Excel file please?

Comment: If you have three areas it doesn't work. How can I upload my workbook?

Answer (score 2):

What worked best for me using MS office 2010 is to use area chart, but not stacked. For multiple data ranges graphs in a single chart, I needed to arrange data legends (column names) from higher to lower, by clicking on the chart and then under "Chart Tools"->"Design" tab click "Select Data". A new window titled "Select Data Source" will pop up. Select data legends in the left pane in the window and move up or down using arrow button on top of the left pane such that graphs will stack from high to low. Now, we need to select graphs corresponding to lower end of the range and fill solid "white" by formatting the graph. What will be left is range chart with shaded area between low and high ends of the data. It seems bit complex, but doing a hand-on tutorial, following the above instructions step-by-step on a chart in excel or power point (after selecting insert chart option), will make it easy.

Comment: This renders an opaque white, hiding the gridlines. Not what OP (or I :) )wants.